# Internal Compiler error from HHVM build

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, archlinux, hhvm

I have been trying to build hhvm from the AUR package using `makepkg -s`. The build is being performed on a pretty basic VM single core with 1GB of RAM (I mention this because I have read it may be solved by using more cores). I receive the following errors when he build is about 24% complete.

```
Scanning dependencies of target hphp_system
[ 24%] Building CXX object hphp/system/CMakeFiles/hphp_system.dir/class_map.cpp.o
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://bugs.archlinux.org/> for instructions.
hphp/system/CMakeFiles/hphp_system.dir/build.make:117: recipe for target 'hphp/system/CMakeFiles/hphp_system.dir/class_map.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [hphp/system/CMakeFiles/hphp_system.dir/class_map.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1213: recipe for target 'hphp/system/CMakeFiles/hphp_system.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [hphp/system/CMakeFiles/hphp_system.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Can I fix this by using a different compiler or compiling directly instead of using PKGBUILD?

Comment: I take it this is using gcc? Which version?

Comment: Yeah I was using 4.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran out of memory. GCC needs a ton of RAM to compile HHVM since it uses lots of templates and meta programming.

Either increase the RAM on your VM or use the precompiled package.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there any advantage to compiling it yourself ? I mean, for an end user, not a developer.

Comment: No. It won't be any faster. You only want to compile it if you need some flags turned on that I didn't turn on when building the packages.

Comment: Is there any precompiled packages for Arch ?